# Treeview Website.sitemap get selected node

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, treeview, sitemapprovider, web.sitemap

I want to be able to bind a treeview with a sitemap data provider in asp.net, and when a user clicks on a node it not navigate to that page, but to update a textbox.

I'm not sure if it is possible and struggling to find any suggestions on how I might achieve this.

I also use VB.Net as the coding language.

Answer (score 0):

This has to be done using JavaScript. Use a function that prevents the default click action on each of the nodes and put the value from the tree into the textbox.

E.g. using JQuery...

```
$(".nodes").click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    $("#<%= TextBox.ClientID").text($(this).text());
});
```